# Añadir nombre del fichero a un data frame

Tags: r

Tengo varios excels con la misma estructura:

```
COL1  COL2
1      2
3      4
5      6
```

Leo los datos:

```
lista1 <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls")


df_list <- lapply(lista1,
                  FUN = function(files) {
                  read.table(files, header = TRUE, sep = "") })
```

Unifico todos los ficheros en un df:

```
library(data.table)
tabla <- rbindlist(df_list)
```

Lo que me quedaría algo como esto:

```
  COL1  COL2
    1      2
    3      4
    5      6
    7      8
    9      10
    11     12
```

Quiero añadirle, me da igual como otra columna o como nombre de fila, el nombre del
fichero donde estaba el dato

```
 COL1  COL2        COL3
    1      2     fichero1.xls
    3      4     fichero1.xls
    5      6     fichero1.xls
    7      8     fichero2.xls
    9      10    fichero2.xls
    11     12    fichero2.xls
```

He probado con bucles replicando el nombre 3 veces pero no doy con la tecla.

```
df$col3[j]<-rep(i,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer el argumento `idcol =`  de la misma función `rbindlist` que estás usando.

Asegúrate de que la lista `df_list` sea una lista nombrada y que los nombres de cada elemento sean el nombre del archivo.

Cuando unes a los data.frame usa `idcol = "COL3"`. No puedo verificarlo al no tener los archivos, pero debería funcionar.

```
lista1 <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls")

df_list <- lapply(lista1,
                  FUN = function(files) {
                  read.table(files, header = TRUE, sep = "") })

names(df_list) <- lista1

library(data.table)

tabla <- rbindlist(df_list, idcol = "COL3")
```

Comment: funciona pefecto. Gracias.
pd: falta cerrar comillas en "COL3

Comment: Corregido, gracias.